# setContent() method of tinyMCE script not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce

There is a problem with execution of the following statement:

```
tinyMCE.get('div_id_name').setContent(headerText);
```

This statement is working fine with all the browsers except Mozilla Firefox (mine is 9.0).

### tinyMCE init code..

Hi,Plz find the code below,hope it would be helpful.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "exact",
    elements: "mceBodyInput",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_css: "/_scripts/tiny_mce/themes/ui_custom.css",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: buttons,
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "external",
    theme_advanced_default_background_color: "#eeeeee",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    theme_advanced_fonts: "Arial=Arial, Geneva;",

    plugins: "autoresize,paste,noneditable",

    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            var e = tinymce.DOM.get(ed.id + '_tbl');
            var ifr = tinymce.DOM.get(ed.id + '_ifr');
            e.style.height = (ifr.clientHeight - 2) + "px";
        });
        ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed) {
            tinyMCE.moveToolbar(ed);
            var sl = document.getElementById("sectionLabel");
            if ($("editAreaDiv").style.visibility == "hidden") {
                sl.innerHTML = "";
            } else {
                switch (ed.id) {
                case "mceHeaderInput":
                    sl.innerHTML = "&#151; Header";
                    break;
                case "mceBodyInput":
                    sl.innerHTML = "&#151; Body";
                    break;
                case "mcePaymentInput":
                    sl.innerHTML = "&#151; Payment Instructions";
                    break;
                case "mceSignatureInput":
                    sl.innerHTML = "&#151; Signature";
                    break;
                case "mceFooterInput":
                    sl.innerHTML = "&#151; Footer";
                    break;
                default:
                    sl.innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
        });

        ed.onActivate.add(function(ed) {
            ed.getBody().style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });
        ed.onDeactivate.add(function(ed) {
            ed.getBody().style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeee";
        });
    },

    onpageload: "hideEditor"
});
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `headerText`? Is `div_id_name` unique on the page?

Comment: headerText value is empty and the div_id_name is unique. I checked putting alerts in javascript function, browser stops execution at that statement.

Comment: @PoornaAnu: Press Ctrl-Shift-K to open the console and check the error message.

Comment: @ Wladimir Palant:  I get following message after Ctrl-Shift-K


[14:20:58.640] The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a problem in case the inserted content is empty.
You can check if `headerText.length > 0` and depending on this insert or not insert the content. If you really need to insert anything at all you may use the tinymce way and set the content to "&#65279 ;";

Comment: even if I add content like <span> hi </span> to headerText, it will fail to excecute setContent() method.   But in chrome it works fine, even with empty headerText value.

Comment: this cannot be. can you file a jsfiddle example for us?

Comment: Sorry @Thariama am not so familiar with the jsfiddle, so let me provide some more info on this..     am trying to display report using tinyMCE features. 
1. The report data i will get from xml file using ajax request.
2. Then am passing those data to tinyMCE script functions, like the one above.
3. Following are 2 more tinyMCE function which are not working in Firefox.. <br>

 tinyMCE.get('mceBodyInput').dom.getRoot().style.fontFamily = defaultFont;

Comment: ok, but can you at least post your full tinymce init? btw. tinyMCE.get('content').dom.getRoot().style.fontFamily = 'tahoma'; works fine on my system with FF

Comment: thanks for your init, using your init on my system is not possible - there seem to be some errors. please set up a jsfiddle demo, here is a link to a working tinymce jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pwb4F/2/

Comment: you may use that fiddle and adjust it to your settings